# MaxMin Divide And Conquer algorithm that is O(N) worst case

Tags: math

This algorithm has a T(N) of O(N^2), worst case. When its to the power of two, it's O(N). However I need to find a way for it to be O(N) in worst case. Any thoughts?

```
max_min(A, i, j, max, min)
{ 
  if(i==j)  -----------> 0 comparisons  
 {
     max=min=A[i];  
   return (max,min);  
  } 
   if(i=j-1)  
  { 
      if(A[i]>A[j])   -------------> 1 comparisons  
     { 
        max=A[i];  
        min=A[j]; 
      }  
     else   
    { 
        max=A[j];   
        min=A[i];
    }
  }
  else 
 {  
   mid=(i+j)/2; ----> O(1)   
  (max1,min1)=max_min(A, i, mid, max, min);  --->T(n/2)  
   // if T(n) is complexity for n elements
  (max2,min2)=max_min(A, mid+1, j, max. min); ---->T(n/2)     
    if(max1>max2)  ---> 1 comparisons   
      max=max1;
    else  
      max=max2; 
    if(min1>min2)  ---> 2 comparisons  
      min=min2;   
    else  
     min=min1; 
  }  
  return(max,min);
}
```

Comment: Why even bother with dividing and conquering? Just iterate the array elements and remember the minimum and maximum element.

Comment: What makes you think the complexity of this is O(n^2) in the worst case? The recurrence relation looks like T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(1).

Comment: When using the master thorem, T(n) = 2T(n/2) +2

Comment: this means c =2, 2> log2(2) hence f(n) = O(N^2) hence T(N) = O(n^2) worst case

Comment: Please, use consistent *and* sensible indentation.

Comment: Why divide and conquer? Because at the bottom of the recursion two elements take only one comparison. The iterative equivalent is to find the min and max of disjoint pairs, each using one comparison, and then iterate through the n/2 mins to find the minimum and through the n/2 maxes to find the maximum. 3n/2 or so comparisons instead of 2n or so.

Answer (score 0):

```
T(2) = 1
T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 2
```

has the solution (confirmed by substitution into the above)

```
T(n) = (3/2)n - 2
```

which is exact for n a power of 2 where the recurrence is exact at all levels of recursion and doesn't need floors and ceilings to be stated properly.

As we know from a proof of the master theorem, floors and ceilings don't change the asymptotic behavior of the solution, so T(n) is linear time in general. So there's no question to answer.